# Adding code to each function call in C

Tags: c, keil

I'm working on a medium-sized `ARM` project with `Keil`.

I need to execute some code when calling a function (every function) for debugging purposes.

Now, I've found online ways to do this with compilers like `gcc` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292149/how-to-add-print-statements-in-every-function-in-c-files-right-programmatically)) but nothing for `Keil`.

How can I do this with `Keil`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't Keil using `armcc`? Take a look how to do it with `armcc`: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/CHDCEBEE.html

Comment: I'll try and get back to you as soon as possibile... thank you!

Comment: That worked! Post it as an answer please, I'll mark it as solution